# When working with Jquery Ajax with async to false, Bootstrap Modal only shows when the request complete

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap 3.3.2 version. I have a form where I have frequent jquery ajax calls and I am trying to show or hide the bootstrap modal dialog box for "Loading" purpose. These all ajax call are set to async false because I need some order in the execution. What I noted is the the bootstrap modal only show when the server completed its request while I have set the modal to show in beforeSend part of Jquery.

I doubt the bootstrap show is an async request because when I am working with other thing like showing a loading image, then its working fine. I am attaching my code here as well. Please advise me some solution for this.

Comment: Hmm..not seeing any code though.

Comment: Just tried that in jsfiddle and works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/ey3ubpt7/. Please share your code.